# Using this keyword with ObjectMapper

Tags: java, jackson, this, objectmapper

I have implemented a method in a POJO which I want to use to convert that object into a Json string.

```
public class Plan implements Stringer {

  private long id;
  private String planId;
  private String planName;



 @Override
  public String getAsString() {
    try {
      return EntityMapper.getInstance().writeValueAsString(this);
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

My EntityMapper is:

```
@Data
public class EntityMapper {

  private static ObjectMapper mapper;

  private EntityMapper() {
  }

  public static ObjectMapper getInstance() {
    if (mapper == null) {
      mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    }
    return mapper;
  }
}
```

When I call this like `plan.getAsString()` I get a `StackOverflowError`
However, if I change this to

```
  public String getAsString(Object obj) {
    try {
      return EntityMapper.getInstance().writeValueAsString(obj);
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
  }
```

and call it like `plan.getAsString(plan)` it works.
Can someone help me understand why this is happening?
I am using Java 11 and the latest version of the ObjectMapper

Comment: Your `getAsString` method (in the first snippet) appears as a property to Jackson because it follows the bean naming convention. Change its name to something else that doesn't follow the bean naming convention or annotate it with `@JsonIgnore`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis thanks a lot! this worked. But just curious whether this is a correct way for considering which fields need to be populated in the json? for example if i have another get method in the pojo it would be populated as a field in the json right?

Comment: You could avoid this issue altogether by separating the JSON serialization logic (`Stringer` interface) from the data types. But, yes, Jackson, by default, relies on the Java bean conventions for detecting properties, ie. anything with `get` (method without parameters), `set` (method with a single parameter), or `is`.